# Upgrade Angular 2 to Angular 4 has no exported member it, describe, expect

Tags: angular, typescript

while migration of Angular 2 to Angular 4 I am getting node_modules/@angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'it' and same for  'describe', 'expect'

> node_modules/@angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'it'.

package.json as follows shown below :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.1",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@ngrx/core": "1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "2.2.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.9",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "font-awesome": "4.2.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.0",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "moment": "2.13.0",
    "ng2-translate": "2.5.0",
    "ngrx-store-logger": "0.1.6",
    "primeng": "4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
    "codelyzer": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.0-xentry",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
```

Comment: add your package.json file

Comment: @Jonnysai Thanks, I have added package.json